# How do I get domestic shipping rates via the USPS API using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, xml, api, google-apps-script, usps

Upon loading this link, which is composed of the user ID provided by USPS and details regarding the package, in my browser

```
Link: http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request USERID="[userid]"><Revision/><Package ID="1ST"><Service>PRIORITY</Service><ZipOrigination>02211</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>90210</ZipDestination><Pounds>5</Pounds><Ounces>2</Ounces><Container>RECTANGULAR</Container><Size>LARGE</Size><Width>15</Width><Length>30</Length><Height>15</Height><Girth>55</Girth></Package></RateV4Request>
```

I am returned with the correct result (below)

```
<RateV4Response>
  <Package ID="1ST">
    <ZipOrigination>02211</ZipOrigination>
    <ZipDestination>90210</ZipDestination>
    <Pounds>5</Pounds>
    <Ounces>2</Ounces>
    <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container>
    <Size>LARGE</Size>
    <Width>15</Width>
    <Length>30</Length>
    <Height>15</Height>
    <Zone>8</Zone>
    <Postage CLASSID="1">
      <MailService>Priority Mail 2-Day&lt;sup&gt;&#8482;&lt;/sup&gt;</MailService>
      <Rate>86.65</Rate>
    </Postage>
  </Package>
</RateV4Response>
```

However, when trying to load the API from a function in Google Apps Script editor using the following block of code:

```
function xmlLoader(){
  var pounds = 5;
  var ounces = 2;
  var userid = "[userid]";
  var url = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll";
  var options =
    {
      "API" : "RateV4",
      "XML" : "<RateV4Request USERID=\"" + userid + "\"> \
                 <Revision/> \
                 <Package ID=\"1ST\"> \
                   <Service>PRIORITY</Service> \
                   <ZipOrigination>02211</ZipOrigination> \
                   <ZipDestination>90210</ZipDestination> \
                   <Pounds>" + pounds + "</Pounds> \
                   <Ounces>" + ounces + "</Ounces> \
                   <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container> \
                   <Size>LARGE</Size> \
                   <Width>15</Width> \
                   <Length>30</Length> \
                   <Height>15</Height> \
                   <Girth>55</Girth> \
                 </Package> \
               </RateV4Request>"
    };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
};
```

This is the error I am returned with,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Error>
    <Number>80040B19</Number>
    <Description>XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed.</Description>
    <Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source>
  </Error>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please be aware that SO is an international forum, and if you don't say what country you are from, we have no idea what you mean by "domestic". (Oh, I guess "USPS" might give a clue - something like US postal service or US parcels service, perhaps?)

Comment: Your comment made me curious whether or not there are identifiers for what country I'm referring to, which is the United States. The most definite way would be to do a WHOIS on the domain I linked [shippingapis.com](http://www.shippingapis.com) which would provide you with the owner's name, address, phone number, and email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any usps ID so I can't do the full test, but for me the problem come from the the URLFetch arguments you are giving. try this code:

```
function xmlLoader(){
  var pounds = 5;
  var ounces = 2;
  var userid = "1000"; //"[userid]";
  var url = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll";
  var payload =
    {
      "API" : "RateV4",
      "XML" : "<RateV4Request USERID=\"" + userid + "\"> \
                 <Revision/> \
                 <Package ID=\"1ST\"> \
                   <Service>PRIORITY</Service> \
                   <ZipOrigination>02211</ZipOrigination> \
                   <ZipDestination>90210</ZipDestination> \
                   <Pounds>" + pounds + "</Pounds> \
                   <Ounces>" + ounces + "</Ounces> \
                   <Container>RECTANGULAR</Container> \
                   <Size>LARGE</Size> \
                   <Width>15</Width> \
                   <Length>30</Length> \
                   <Height>15</Height> \
                   <Girth>55</Girth> \
                 </Package> \
               </RateV4Request>"
    };

  var options={
    method:"POST",
    payload:payload
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
};
```

have a look at the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String,Object%29)

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks for saving me a few more days of headache

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that both USPS and UPS don't have the greatest of XML interpreters. I found this article searching for a syntax problem parsing an HTML entity for an ampersand in a company name. (which should be supported in XML but apparently it causes USPS to puke)
Some of them are also very picky on the 'order'. As in, the element order will cause errors if not followed exactly as their documentation specifies. I have also run into issues on fields they 'claim' are optional but that aren't - I needed to send an 'empty' tag - and others that puked on empty tags.
Still another thing I ran into yesterday, the verify address api seems to like to flip address1 and address2 around, but only on output. (on input it pukes if you send just address2).